# Moderators can close question without voting. Do they have too much power to restrict the discussion?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, moderation

I saw that there are a lot of similar questions. But I noticed that only recently moderators started closing questions bypassing the usual voting, one moderator is enough to close it, like [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71832/does-it-make-sense-to-keep-the-iss-in-operation-and-force-the-western-countries?noredirect=1#comment295457_71832).

So my question is only about this feature. Doesn't it give them the ability to constrain the discussion on the forum according to their opinion?

Comment: Elected moderators (the ones with the ♦ symbol) have binding close votes. That’s one of the privileges the community elected them for. Why do you assume that this question was closed only _“according to their opinion”_? The question was closed according to the site’s rules, defined in the [help center](//politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You can still contest any close vote, so the feature is fine as it is.

Comment: If what moderators did was not in agreement with the site rules, then they would be removed as moderators.

Comment: A few of the related questions: [Please don't allow a single mod the ability to close a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318826/273494), [Should moderators close questions for reasons other than obvious violation of the rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78748/273494), [Policy concerning unilateral closing of questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277080/273494)

Comment: While we mods sometimes *want* to vote a question for closure without a binding vote, most of the time they are entrusted to close unilaterally based on the site policy and to close it *as quickly as possible*. The same for mod's binding reopen votes.

Comment: If you believed that it was closed wrongly, vote to reopen it. If you believe the mod is abusing their power, raise it on the per-site meta or send a support ticket to stack exchange CMs. Bringing the issue to the main meta achieves nothing. (Also, the reason your question was closed was explained to you in the comments, I don't understand your problem with it.)

Comment: [The Stack Exchange sites are ***not*** forums](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) (fora?). They are [think tanks](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Answer (score 18):

We aren't forums, and we generally avoid discussions.

Questions are asked, answers given, and...

Fundamentally - mods are *trusted* to be able to close questions unilaterally, and to basically make those decisions. It *is* a lot of power, but there's 2 checks against it - that the community can vote to reopen, and the question can be discussed on meta.

I notice there's some discussion in comments about the question - 2 close votes (though I can't see how many re-open votes) and so on. There's reasons given - and keeping questions on topic *is* a valid use of a mod closure, though practically the community on my sites beat me to it.